# Unable to check JWT validity in AuthGuard in angular 6?

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6

I have created an angular app with simple login page and dashboard. The dashboard is a secure page and should open after valid login.

On the submit button I am calling an authentication service to check the validity of user credential and on the response, I receive a JWT, which is stored in local storage.

I have also created an AuthGuard to protect the dashboard. In the AuthGuard I am not able to identify whether this JWT is valid or not (any user can create some random key and get access to the dashboard).

**Do I have to create some method in Dashboard Init() method to check the validity of JWT and if so then what is the purpose of AuthGuard? Please suggest.**

login.component.ts:

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.f.userName.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        },
        error => {
          // this.error = error;
          // this.loading = false;
        });
```

authenticationservice.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:59900/api/login', { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response&& user.token
                debugger;
                if (user ) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
                return user;
            }));
    }
```

AuthGuard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        debugger;
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it enough to check if currentUser is inside local storage ?  anyone can set a currentUser in his localStorage and will bypass your Guard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saving tokens in localStorage You should acknowledge risk that user can change it and set own token. But as I guess you have some back-end service which is checking validity of access or refresh tokens. So if you need to validate user token with guard you can send some request to back-end from guard and if user is authenticated (means token is valid) then return true. Anyways If you are returning some info from back-end with Authorization, any user needs to have valid token. Will you do it from guard or just from page. 
I, for example prefer check token validity outside guard. On controller initialization (OnInit).

Please keep in mind that you must not to save or load application protected data from back-end without authorization.

What about: **Do I have to create some method in Dashboard Init() method to check the validity of JWT and if so then what is the purpose of AuthGuard? Please suggest.**

usually users will not add local storage items manually, so you can check only if token exists.

Also, I am using angular jwt which is package from Auth0. `https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt`
using package I am checking if token expired. See my code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)  {  
  const refToken = refreshTokenGetter();
  const helper = new JwtHelperService();
  const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(refToken);

  if (refToken && !isExpired) {
      return true;
  }

  this.router.navigate(['auth']);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what IsTokenExpired method does? Is It checks the token expiration of token on the server or at the client side?

Comment: It checks token expiration in client side. It's working using JwtHelperService, which is part of angular-jwt package (package created by auth0). As I sad you should check validity of jwt in back-end too, but it is not necessary to do it from guard. You can do it anywhere before send data from back to front. Choose best option for example for performance.